# Angular: how can I set [placeholder] with multiple conditions

Tags: angular, typescript

How can I set placeholder depending on multiple possible values ?
I tried this:

```html
[placeholder]="{
   'Type your answer here...': question.type === 'text',
   'address@example.com': question.type === 'email',
   '00 00 00 00 00': question.type === 'phone'
}"
```

But this does not work and display `[object Object]` in input field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `placeholder` attribute does not accept an object like `ngClass` does, it expects a string. You could create a method on your component which returns the appropriate string based on the question type.

```
private placeholders: { [key: string]: string } = {
  text: 'Type your answer here...',
  email: 'address@example.com',
  phone: '00 00 00 00 00'
};

public getPlaceholder(questionType: string): string {
  return this.placeholders[questionType] || 'Default placeholder';
}
```

Use it in your template like so:

```
[placeholder]="getPlaceholder(question.type)"
```

Comment: if you make public the object "placeholders" you can use directly `<input [placeholder]="placeholders[question.type] || 'Default placeholder'">`

Answer (score 1):

You should move logic code to ts file, create method to return place holder as

```
getPlaceHolder() {
    if (this.question.type === "text") return "Type your answer here...";
    if (this.question.type === "email") return "address@example.com";
    if (this.question.type === "phone") return "00 00 00 00 00";
  }
```

Input tag

```
<input type="text" [placeholder]="getPlaceHolder()" />
```

Demo https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-lkb1uq?